# React Native Expo: Cannot Read property 'watchPosition of undefined

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, geolocation

I am trying to get the location from mobile devices using the navigator.geolocation.watchPosition() function but I am receiving an error. I granted the Permissions in the useEffect().This is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getPermissions = async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        console.log("Please grant location permissions");
        return;
      }

      let currentLocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(currentLocation);
      console.log(`latitude: ${currentLocation.coords.latitude}`);
      console.log(currentLocation);
    };
    getPermissions();
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        console.log(position);
      },
      (error) => {
        Alert.alert("Error", error.message);
      },
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    );
  }, []);
```

[image: Error Message]

I have tried installing expo-location package without success, the error persist.